# How to ensure your own success over the priorities of others

Tags: sentence-meaning

> How to ensure your own success over the priorities of others.
>   (Source: [link](https://themission.co/start-doing-these-9-things-for-yourself-every-day-to-improve-your-life-this-year-294f67b386d0))

What is the meaning of ***"over the priorities of others"***? Does it mean the judgement or success of others"

Comment: Welcome to Ell. What's your question exactly?

Comment: The meaning of "over the priorities of others"does it mean the judgement,success of others or not to prioritise others over your own success?thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, you can add anything you want to your question by clicking on the "edit" icon.

Answer (score 2):

The preposition **over** literally means "occupying a position above something" and figuratively "having a higher priority or importance than something".

You can place your own success "over" the priorities of others, or treat your own success as more important than their success or as more important than their concerns and interests.

It is a little awkward, stylistically, to say "ensure ... over", but it would mean "arrange things so that your own success is assured, even if other people have  priorities which are not in sync with yours, or have competing interests."

Answer (score 0):

*X over Y* means X is on top of Y.

It can also be figuratively used to express that X succeeds in a competition between X and Y, or X succeeds despite/regardless of Y.

> I will choose candy over vegetables every time.

So ...

> How to ensure your own success over the priorities of others

This means how to ensure you succeed even though the priorities of others may be interfering.